# Opening a new viewcontroller through navigation controller after pressing an alert action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to open a different view controller after pressing an alert action in my original view controller. How can I do this by using navigation controller?

```
 func showAlert()
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Selection", message: "Please select which 
    type of stats you would like to view", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Team Stats", style: .default, handler:
    {
        action in print("tapped team stats")
        
    }))
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Player Stats", style: .default, handler:
    {
        action in print("tapped player stats")
        
    }))
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:
    {
        action in print("tapped dismiss")

    }))
    
    
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private func showTeamStats() {
  let teamVC = YourTeamViewController()
  navigationController?.pushViewController(teamVC, animate:true)
}

private func showplayerStats() {
  let playerVC = YourPlayerViewController()
  navigationController?.pushViewController(playerVC, animate:true)
}


 func showAlert()
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Selection", message: "Please select which 
    type of stats you would like to view", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Team Stats", style: .default, handler:
    {
        self.showTeamStats()
        
    }))
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Player Stats", style: .default, handler:
    {
        self.showPlayerStats()
        
    }))
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:
    {
        action in print("tapped dismiss")
        alert.dismiss(animated:true)

    }))
    
    
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Note: It will work only if your parent view controller embedded in navigation controller

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, I tried writing those two functions, but every time my app tries to navigate to the new viewcontroller, it just shows up as a black screen with a "back" button in the navigation bar, so it is not working.(And yes, my navigation controller is embedded in the storyboard!)

Comment: the black screen is your view controller screen where you navigate and if there is back bar button at the top so it means you navigated to a new controller.

Comment: and maybe the view controller where you navigate has nothing on it. just change the back ground color of the view of that controller. "view.backgroundColor = .red" inside viewDidLoad() function